# Webapi depedency injection

Tags: asp.net-web-api, unity-container

Hej,

I am working on asp.net Webapi. When I try to inject value in my repository constructor so It throws an Exception.
Resolution of the dependency failed,

> type = "Controllers.XXXXX", name = "(none)"

. Exception occurred while: while resolving. Exception is:

> InvalidOperationException - The current type, IRepository, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping? -----------------------------------------------

I am doing registration like that

```
string modelMapperName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        container.RegisterType<IBulkCopy, BulkCopy>("bulkCopy", new InjectionConstructor("dbo", "test"));

        container.RegisterType<IMapConfigurator, ProductMap>(modelMapperName, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

        container.RegisterType<IModelMapper, ModelAutoMapper>(modelMapperName,
            new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<IMapConfigurator>(modelMapperName)));

        container.RegisterType<IProductRepository, EProductRepository>("productRepository", new PerResolveLifetimeManager(),
             new InjectionConstructor(
                new ResolvedParameter<IRepositoryFactory>(DatabaseConnection.XXXX)
                , new ResolvedParameter<IModelMapper>(modelMapperName),
                new ResolvedParameter<IBulkCopy>("bulkCopy")));
```

When I remove ResolvedParamater from the `IProductRepository` mappings so it works fine. Could anybody help me to identify this problems.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't register `IRepositoryFactory` anywhere.

Comment: Can you post the constructor signature for your "EProductRepository"?

Comment: Thanks for your response and help. I have solved the issue. The issue was I was not sending parameter to my controller constructor through unity so thats the reason I was getting an issue and unity was unable to resolve depedencies.